# Can't mass-assign protected attributes: category_ids

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, nested-forms, simple-form

I'm using simple_form, and I just want to create association between categories and articles using categorization table.

But I have this error: 
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: category_ids.
app/controllers/articles_controller.rb:36:in `update'

**articles_controller.rb**

```
def update
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
      if @article.update_attributes(params[:article]) ---line with the problem
        flash[:success] = "Статья обновлена"
        redirect_to @article
      else
        render :edit
      end
end
```

**article.rb**

```
has_many :categorizations
has_many :categories, through: :categorizations
```

**category.rb**

```
has_many :categorizations
has_many :articles, through: :categorizations
```

**categorization.rb**

```
belongs_to :article
belongs_to :category
```

categorization has article_id and category_id fields.

My _form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @article, html: { class: "form-horizontal", multipart: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %> 
  <%= f.input :title %>
  <%= f.association :categories %>
  <%= f.input :teaser %>
  <%= f.input :body %>
  <%= f.input :published %>
 <% if @article.published? %>
   <%= f.button :submit, value: "Внести изменения" %>
 <% else %>
   <%= f.button :submit, value: "Опубликовать" %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

do you have attr_accessible in article.rb?

if so add

```
     attr_accessible :title, :category_ids
```

Also make sure you really want this for all forms... If not add this:

```
  attr_accessible :title, :category_ids, :as => :admin
```

then

```
@article = Article.new
@article.assign_attributes({ :category_ids => [1,2], :title => 'hello' })
@article.category_ids # => []
@article.title # => 'hello'

@article.assign_attributes({ :category_ids => [1,2], :title => 'hello' }, :as => :admin)
@article.category_ids # => [1,2]
@article.title # => 'hello'
@article.save
```

or

```
@article = Article.new({ :category_ids => [1,2], :title => 'hello' })
@article.category_ids # => []
@article.title # => 'hello'

@article = Article.new({ :category_ids => [1,2], :title => 'hello' }, :as => :admin)
@article.category_ids # => [1,2]
@article.title # => 'hello'
@article.save
```

Comment: Hi, thank you! That's it I had  attr_accessible :category_id instead of :category_ids

Answer (score 3):

The form field created by

```
<%= f.association :categories %>
```

is going to set the attribute `category_id`, but the attribute is protected. In you model you should have a line of code looks like this:

```
attr_accessible :title, :teaser, :body, :published
```

these attributes are allowed for mass assignment. If you want the form to set `category_id` you have to add these attribute to the `attr_accessible` method:

```
attr_accessible :title, :teaser, :body, :published, :category_id
```

This should fix your issue.

Comment: Hello, Paul, thanks for your response. Yes I had this line, and the problem was in attr_accessible as drhenner pointed out, instead of :category_id there should be :category_ids